# ui table view data source

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

what should I do ?

this is my code of ui table view cell for row path

note that these images come from api calling

> > when I keep scroll in the table view till the cell disappear the image disappear too its like I lose the image source just its background still appear

I have a uiTableView Have many cells , each cell have an image , when I scroll down till cell disappear the images in those cell go !

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    cell = blockListTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlockCell", for: indexPath) as! BlockTableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor(hex: 0xEEEEEE) : UIColor(hex:0x001638 )
    cell.index = indexPath
    imageUrl = imageUrl + blockUsers[indexPath.row].profilePicture
    if blockUsers[indexPath.row].profilePicture == "" {
        cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(named: "blockedUser")
    }
    else {
        
        cell.profilePicture.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl))
    }
    
   
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted two immediate issues in this snippet.

1. When you set the "blockedUser" image to the image view, Kingfisher might still be downloading an image in the background, if the cell was reused. And that would overwrite your static image.

   Be sure to call `cancelDownloadTask` before setting the static image.

   ```swift
   if blockUsers[indexPath.row].profilePicture == "" {
       cell.profilePicture.kf.cancelDownloadTask() // (!)
       cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(named: "blockedUser")
   } else {
       cell.profilePicture.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl))
   }
   ```
2. Every time cellForRowAt is called, the following line is always appending stuff to a *field*, which surely ends up building an invalid URL that is never fixed.

   ```swift
   imageUrl = imageUrl + blockUsers[indexPath.row].profilePicture
   ```

   Since there's not much to go on, I assume you have a "base URL" stored in the
   field, and you want to append a filename at the end of it for the given user.

   If this is the case, you probably wanted to write this instead, making a new local variable instead of overwriting the field:

   ```swift
   let imageUrl = self.imageUrl + blockUsers[indexPath.row].profilePicture
   ```

Comment: image url its the base of my api calling , its work well but the problem when I scroll till cell disappear the image disappear and also the button inside the cell if I pressed on it before scroll till itself disappear

Comment: Are the images still disappearing after applying my fixes above?

Comment: no bro its work thank you but I still have the problem with the button

Comment: I just noticed that you have a field called `cell` as well, don't do that. If other code is accessing that `cell` field, nothing good will happen. This isn't Python, you should use `let` (and sometimes `var`) to make local variables.